# WSO2IS 5.8 - How cleaning captchas without error

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I use the function getCaptcha() from UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub class (org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.stub_5.12.387.jar provided by WSO2IS 5.8), and I have this kind of problem

`ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.captcha.mgt.util.CaptchaUtil} - Error in cleaning old captchas. org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource does not exist at path /_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.captcha-images/0ab1c75d-972a-45da-8be7-17536d06c80d.jpg`

I think WSO2IS 5.8 got lost with this captcha

As things progress, occasionaly, i have this kind of error :

`TID: [2020-05-21 00:07:11,501] ERROR {wso2is.Wso2isServiceManager} - Read timed out {wso2is.Wso2isServiceManager} org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:203) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:81) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:459) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286) at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442) at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:442) at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228) at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149) at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.stub.UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub.getCaptcha(UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub.java:4339)`

After a WSO2IS restart, all is ok for a short time (few days), and we still have this error.

I try to create the missing resource, but it seems not create, i have the same error message "Resource does not exist". The number of captcha created increases rapidly.

How can we fix this permanently?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The "resource does not exist" error can happen due to one of the following reasons

1. Trying to answer a captcha which has already answered.
2. Trying to answer a captcha which validity period has expired.

In both of the above cases, the identity server deletes the records related to the captcha.

Hard to identify the reason for the read timeout with the given information. One possible reason could be the high load.

Cheers,
Isura.

Comment: I try to create the missing resource in the management console (registry), i have the message to wait a several time, but it seems not create.

The error message "resource does not exist" appear when WSO2IS try to clean the old captchas (called by getCaptcha() funtion). The old captchas cleaning is blocked by this captcha, no one are deleted.
Apparently we would have tens of thousands of captchas now, and i don't know how to unlock the situation.

Thanks